# Get SQL data between two dates when date field has time and date in it

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in my sql like: 2018-06-26 07:15:06
Right now I am using: $sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date LIKE '$myDato' ";
$myDato is set as: 2018-06-26%
This works like a charm. I am getting all rows starting with that day.
Now i want to extract more days. I have tried:

```
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date BETWEEN >= '$myDato' AND => '$myDato2'";
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date BETWEEN LIKE '$myDato' AND LIKE '$myDato2'";
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date BETWEEN '$myDato' AND '$myDato2'";
```

but i can't find the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date  >= '$myDato' AND date >= '$myDato2'";
```

If there is something like `%` in the end of date, then following solution can be used.

```
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date  >= '" . substr($myDato, 0, -1) . "' AND date >= '" . substr($myDato2, 0, -1) . "'";
```

`substr($myDato, 0, -1)` will remove the last character from string.

Comment: To avoid SQL injection: use prepared statement instead

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
$sqlq = "Select * from db WHERE date  >= '".$myDato."' AND date <= '".$myDato2."' ";
```

Comment: To avoid SQL injection: use prepared statement instead

Comment: This does not work. The variables is like 2018-06-26% and 2018-06-27%

Comment: @Bergum try now.

Comment: I have tried to change the date to: 2018-06-26 00:00:00 and 2018-06-27 23:59:59 but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from db WHERE date >='2018-06-26 07:15:06' AND date< "2018-06-30 07:15:06";

Answer (score 0):

For example get sql data between '2018-06-26' and '2018-06-27'

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-06-26', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-06-27', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```